# Why is equals involving MariaDB JSON not reflexive?

Tags: mariadb, mysql-json

The following MariaDB statement uses [JSON_EXTRACT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-extract) to turn the JSON-escaped string `a` into a JSON-typed value, and then this value is compared to itself. The comparison comes up as **not equal**. I thought that equality was reflexive (barring tricky things involving NULL and NaN), that is, a value is always equal to itself. What am I misunderstanding?

```
SELECT
JSON_EXTRACT('"a"', '$'),
JSON_EXTRACT('"a"', '$') =
JSON_EXTRACT('"a"', '$');
```

[image: phpmyadmin result of the code above, returning 0 for the comparison]

Server info:

```
Server: Localhost via UNIX socket
Server type: MariaDB
Server connection: SSL is not being used Documentation
Server version: 10.6.7-MariaDB-2ubuntu1-log - Ubuntu 22.04
Protocol version: 10
User: phpmyadmin@localhost
Server charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8mb4)
```

Comment: I ran your query and it showed as equal, maybe its a bug with mariadb?

Comment: Looks like MariaDB issue/bug. Both `=` and `<=>` produces zero. MySQL produces TRUE for the same query. Comparing `CAST(JSON_EXTRACT('"a"', '$') AS CHAR(xxx))` fixes. Maybe this is unescaping issue? https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.6&fiddle=5e441766421a1bb34442037f0325e271 I think that you may report about the bug.

Comment: I have reported the bug and they have confirmed it: [Problems in comparisons using JSON_EXTRACT](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-29396).

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the solution is to use [JSON_EQUALS()](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/json_equals/), which was added in MariaDB 10.7. I don't have an instance of MariaDB 10.7 so I can't test it, and dbfiddle only goes up to MariaDB 10.6.

You can, however, unquote the JSON to extract the string value, and test for equality.

```
SELECT
JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT('"a"', '$')) AS a,
JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT('"a"', '$')) =
JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT('"a"', '$')) AS `a=a`;
```

| a | a=a |
| --- | --- |
| a | 1 |

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.6&fiddle=6fa8c7156e6fe9213bfbf44dd57e2c63

Comment: Another option would be to use [JSON_VALUE](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/json_value/), see [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.6&fiddle=55b26b22d256abfb837b3fa235220b34). Currently [SQL Online](https://sqliteonline.com/) page has a 10.7.x version of MariaDB.